# Is it acceptable to always segue forward or should I eventually pop views off the UINavController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

In an app like Instagram where the main interface is a feed with a button to post a new item. Suppose the user creates a new post which involves multiple screens before eventually getting to a Post screen. The question is - is it ok to perform a segue forward to the 'Feed' screen or should I instead perform multiple popViewController() calls to reverse back to the Feed screen.

Given the user can perform the 'Post' action multiple times and end up with a large stack of circular view controllers I'm inclined to think this isn't good and I should be popping backwards

Comment: You've answered your own question at the end.

Comment: @rmaddy ok thanks - it was my inclination - I guess I just wanted some validation before I went ahead and started making code changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```